# [Clang RecursiveASTVisitor]How to make a distinction between 'If' statement and 'Else If' statement?

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-c++-api

I'm using clang's RecursiveASTVisitor to parse some C code. I override visitStmt() and want to make a distinction between 'If' statement and 'Else If' statement.

Example:

```
    if(a > 0){
      XXX
    }
    else if(a == 0){
      YYY
    }
    else{
      ZZZ
    }
```

In visitStmt(), I use:

```
    if(isa<IfStmt>(S))
```

to judge whether a statement is IfStmt.

**But how can I know the statement is 'Else If' rather than 'If'?**

I want to insert different stubs(XXX under 'If' and YYY under 'Else If').

ps: I'm not a native English speaker. Please forgive me for my poor express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C there is not specific `else if` statement, because

```
if (a) {
  ...
} 
else if (b) {
  ...
} 
else {
  ...
}
```

is conceputally (and in terms of an AST) something like the following

```
if (a) {
  ...
} 
else { 
  if (b) {
    ...
  } 
  else {
    ...
  }
}
```

So the first snippet is sort of a "hidden nesting", because the body of the first `else` just consists of a single `if ... else` statement, so you can omit the `{}` around it. And the last `else` does not belong to the first `if` but to the second.

So what you probably can do to determine whether you have an `else if` or not, is step up in the tree, and check if the parent node of the current node is an `else` statement and the `if` is the *first* (or only) statement in that parent-else's  body.

There are other languages (for instance VB) which have a `If .. ElseIf .. Else` construct. But C doesn't.

Comment: Really thanks. Your answer helps a lot.